# How to override static methods with non static methods?

Tags: php, class

How to override static methods with non static methods?

## code

```
class Env {
    static protected $vars = [
    ];

    static public function get_env_var($var){
        return self::$vars[$var];
    }

    static public function set_env_var($var, $value){
        self::$vars[$var] = $value;
    }
}

class Test extends Env {
    private $env_vars = [];

    public function __construct(){
        $this->env_vars = self::$vars;
    }

    public function get_env_var($var){
        return $this->env_vars[$var];
    }

    public function set_env_var($var, $value){
        $this->env_vars[$var] = $value;
    }
}

$Test = new Test();
```

## error

```
Cannot make static method Env::get_env_var() non static in class Test in
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that? They serve a very different purpose, so overriding doesn't really make sense.

Comment: The error message says it all: Cannot make static method non static

Comment: if you want to call the function without instantiating the class then this is the one the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static function get_env_var($var)
```

Comment: This is not overriding with a _non_ static method, is simple overriding.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

If you defined them as `static` before, you had valid reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Original question was how to override static method to non static. 
Your answer is not the answer for the question, because child is still static.

You can't override a static method with a non static.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent
{
    public static function start()
    {
        echo 'Parent::start';
    }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    public static function start()
    {
        parent::start();
        echo 'Child::start';
    }
}
```